# Is it possible to create a DNN User without creating the membership information?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I have a custom authentication provider to handle the username and passwords. I can create the actual DNN user account without a problem. What I don't want to do is have to repeat or add additional membership information to the aspnet_membership table that DNN uses. ]

I don't want DNN to update fields such as LastActivityDate and the like on the membership tables. I just want to use my authentication provider and a DNN user to manage roles and access within DNN.

**Clarification:**

What I'm really wanting to do is use the DNN UserAuthentication table and a user in the DNN Users table but not have any aspnet_User or aspnet_Membership information associated with it. The Authentication is provided by a separate system - think Twitter or Live ID - I don't want DNN to have any passwords. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create your own provider and replace the ASP.NET Membership provider, there would be nothing writing to those tables, so you will be fine.

Updated Per Clarification

Not directly, but you could do various things to fake out the system if you will, by setting default passwords for the user accounts or similar when you actually go through and create the user.

If you want, e-mail me and I can point you in the right direction.

Comment: My challenge is I don't want multiple login options but I want to keep the default login option. Host, admin, other accounts in the DNN system. Other users will login with existing credentials in another database. I have it do that those users are added as DNN users but I don't want to add membership information for those users. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Mitchel, thanks for the answer. Curious as to if the clarification I added to the question helpful.

Comment: Accepted this answer since it is correct. It is also the direction that I headed for the final solution.